# Javascript: Generating a self executing class that is callable and extendable in window context

Tags: javascript

some beginner question here but i can't seem to find a working answer for my problem. I want to write a self executing, global javascript class 'foo' whose methods can be called from window context (like `window.foo.bar()` or just `foo.bar()` in javascript console), without having to instantiate the class.

At the same time, i want to be able to extend said class with custom functions, e.g.

`foo.fn.baz = function() {}`

This is how far i have gotten this far:

```
(function (window) {
var foo = function() {
    return this;
};
foo.fn = foo.prototype = {
    bar: function (string) {
        console.log(string);
    }
};
window.foo = foo;
})(window);
```

When i execute this javascript, the js console now knows the class foo, and i can *extend* its functions via `foo.fn.baz = function(){}` but i can't *call* those functions: `foo.bar` is undefined.

If i change the code from `window.foo = foo;` to `window.foo = new foo();`, then i can *call* the functions, but i can't *extend* the class anymore.

How do i do this rigt? Is my code anywhere near the right way to do such a thing? Is it even possible to get both things at the same time?

Anyone with an idea or a hint? Anything would be great.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `foo.bar` is undefined

Right. You've put the methods on the `prototype` property of the function. The object that `foo.prototype` refers to will get assigned to *instances* you create via the `new` operator, as their underlying prototype. So:

```
var f = new foo();
f.bar();
```

If you want a singleton (`foo` is, itself, the **one** object and you can call `foo.bar()`), you don't need prototypes at all:

```
window.foo = {
    bar: function(string) {
        console.log(string);
    }
};
```

...but as you used the word "class," my guess is that you really do want to create multiple *instances* using `foo`, rather than using `foo` directly, so `new foo()` would be what you want.

---

Side note: The overwhelming convention in JavaScript is that if a function is expected to be called via `new`, it starts with an upper-case letter. So `Foo` rather than `foo`.

Comment: Hey T.J., thanks for your answer. Seems like i overcomplicated matters incredibly by trying to force structures onto the script that it didn't really need. The singleton solution is completely sufficient for my needs. Thanks for clearing my view.